# How to force abstract and introduction to stay on the same page in LaTeX?

Tags: abstract

I need to write with LaTeX the `\begin{abstract}` before `\chapter*{Introduction}` on the same page. I am using the following document class: `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}` with `\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap}
\begin{document}
\microtypesetup{activate=true}
\allowhyphens
\counterwithin*{subsection}{chapter}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\begingroup
\begin{abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\end{abstract}
\cleardoublepage
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although your specific problem seems to be caused by a `\cleardoublepage` where you don’t want one, in general: You can use `\nopagebreak` where you do not want there to be a page break. You might also suggest a `\pagebreak` (or perhaps `\pagebreak[1]`) after the introduction, to encourage the page-breaking algorithm to break after, not before.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the code you showed in the question does not compile, so I'll assume some generic definition for the abstract environment.

You can avoid the automatic page break at the start of a new chapter by temporarily redefining `\cleardoublepage`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap}

\newenvironment{abstract}{}{\par}

\begin{document}
%\microtypesetup{activate=true}
%\allowhyphens
\counterwithin*{subsection}{chapter}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{\relax}
\begin{abstract}
some text
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\end{abstract}
%\cleardoublepage
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```